# Sätze mit "als" in der Vergangenheit

Tags: grammaticality

Ich hab schon längst bemerkt, dass wir bei Sätzen mit "als" in der Vergangenheit oft Präteritum und Perfekt in einem Satz benützen. Also Präteritum im Teil mit "als" und Perfekt in dem anderen. Zum Beispiel:

> Als Metall auf Metall traf, sind die Funken nur so gestoben.

Gibt's eine feste Regel dafür, oder ist es nur eine häufig vorkommende Kombination?

Comment: Where did you read it? A book, a newspaper, a learning resource? As a rule of thumb, Germans tend to be very lax in the way they use or combine tenses.

Comment: It was in the board game "Wie gut ist Ihr Deutsch?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dein Beispielsatz beginnt nicht in der Vergangenheit, sondern in der Gegenwart der Erzählung. Das ist das, was Präteritum markiert. Eigentlich müsste man die Erzähung auch mit Präteritum fortsetzen, aber der Autor dieses Satzes hat sich anders entschieden.

Er wählt Perfekt, was die Vergangenheit der Wirklichkeit markiert, und spannt so einen Bogen zwischen Erzählung und Wirklichkeit. Dadurch wird das Sprühen der Funken lebendiger. Sie sind in diesem erzählerischen Kontext als „wirklich“ hervorgehoben.

Der nächste Satz müsste im Präsens oder Perfekt stehen, da die Erzählung ja vorbei ist. Beginnt man stattdessen wieder mit Präteritum, würde ich es als Zuhörer oder Leser so deuten, dass eine neue Szene begonnen wird. Das kann natürlich auch einfach nur ein Perspektivwechsel sein.

> Der Schmied und sein Geselle hämmerten und schwitzten im Feuerschein, und einen Riesenlärm haben sie gemacht!

Wieder genau dasselbe, der Riesenlärm wird mit Perfekt als wirklich markiert und damit dem Leser bewusster.

Comment: Vielen herzlichen Dank, wirklich ausführlich erläutert.